# How to create nntplib objects using Multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

trying for 2 days to get multiprocessing to work when creating connections to an NNTP server. Goal: make a bunch of connections (like 50) as fast as possible. As making connections can be slow in a for loop (like upto 10 sec), i want to make them all 'at once' using multiprocessing. After creation of the connections, they remain open, as 10,000+ request will be made in some future multiprocessing part, relying on similar principle.

Some simplified part of the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import ssl
from nntplib import NNTP_SSL
from multiprocessing import Pool 

def MakeCon(i, host, port):
    context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
    s = NNTP_SSL(host, port=port, ssl_context=context, readermode=True)
    print('created connection', i)  # print to see progress
    sys.stdout.flush()
    return s

def Main():
    host = 'reader.xsnews.nl'
    port = 563
    num_con = 4

    y=MakeCon(1, host, port).getwelcome()  #request some message from NNTP host to see if it works
    print(y)

    # the actual part that has the issue:
    if __name__ == '__main__':

        cons = range(num_con)
        s = [None] * num_con
        pool = Pool()
        for con in cons:
            s[con]=pool.apply_async(MakeCon, args=(con, host, port))
        pool.close

        print(s[1])
        for con in cons:
            t=s[con].getwelcome()  #request some message from NNTP host to see if it works
            print(t)

        print('end')

Main()
```

Showing that the connection to the NNTP server etc works, but I fail at the part to extract the connections into some object I can use in combination with the nntplib options. I would say I ain't that experienced with python, especially not multiprocessing.

Comment: Are you trying to create multiple connections to the same news server?

Comment: @JohanL Thanks, yes, and as fast as possible, so I don't like too loop over the NNTP_SSL() / NNTP(), as each time there could be a waiting time of say 1 sec before the connection is established. Thats why I would like to create them 'simultaneously' using multiprocessing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different issues with your approach. The biggest is that it won't work to create the connection in different processes and then send them to the main process. This is because each connection opens a socket and sockets are not serializable (pickable) and can therefore not be sent between processes.

And even if it had worked, the usage of `.apply_sync()` is not the right way to go. It is better to use `.map()` which returns the output from the function call directly (as opposed to `.apply_sync()` that returns an object from which the return value can be extracted).

However, in the current situation, the program is I/O bound, rather than CPU bound, and in these situations threading works just as well as multiprocessing, since the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) won't hold back the execution. Thus, changing to threads instead of multiprocessing and to `.map()`from `.apply_sync()` gives the following solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import ssl
from nntplib import NNTP_SSL
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool 

def MakeCon(i, host, port):
    context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
    s = NNTP_SSL(host, port=port, ssl_context=context, readermode=True)
    print('created connection', i)  # print to see progress
    sys.stdout.flush()
    return s

def Main():
    host = 'reader.xsnews.nl'
    port = 563
    num_con = 4

    y=MakeCon(1, host, port).getwelcome()  #request some message from NNTP host to see if it works
    print(y)
    return con

    cons = range(num_con)
    s = [None] * num_con
    pool = ThreadPool()
    s=pool.map(lambda con: MakeCon(con, host, port), cons)
    pool.close

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

A small word of advice, though. Be careful with creating too many connections, since that might not be looked to nicely upon from the server, since you are draining resources doing this.

Also, if you are to use your different connections to fetch articles these calls should probably also be done in different threads.

And, as a final comment, the same effect as using threads is to use `asyncio`. That, however, is something you probably need to study a while before you feel comfortable using.

Comment: The sockets work nicely and a lot faster. I used the same principle for the created sockets to request headers via function `check_id()`, to loop list `ids`:`j = itertools.cycle(range(len(socks)))` followed by `t = pool.map(lambda id: check_id(socks, next(j), id), ids)` This approach becomes slightly faster for 4 sockets compared to 1, but for say 10 there is no gain. (ping and latency are very low to the server). Guess the cycle method stalls it, as a typical socket is not freed yet. (before I used `socket` i/o `nntplib`, and did loop a lot to avoid `asyncio`)